# Using JEuclid to generate formula in PDF(XSL-FO)

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo, apache-fop, mathml

I am trying to transform an xml to pdf which contains formulas. I have added jeuclid jars to handle formula. Whole xml is transformed properly except the formulas. I am getting blank where there are formulas.

```
public class PDFCreation {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PDFCreation pdfCreation = new PDFCreation();
        try {
            pdfCreation.convertToPDF("SPE.xsl", "IPTC-19048-MS.xml", "IPTC-19048-MS.pdf");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void convertToPDF(String xsl, String xml, String pdf) throws IOException, FOPException, TransformerException {
        File xsltFile = new File(xsl);
        StreamSource xmlSource = new StreamSource(new File(xml));
        FopFactory fopFactory = FopFactory.newInstance(new File(".").toURI());
        FOUserAgent foUserAgent = fopFactory.newFOUserAgent();
        OutputStream out;
        out = new java.io.FileOutputStream(pdf);
        try {
            Fop fop = fopFactory.newFop(MimeConstants.MIME_PDF, foUserAgent, out);
            TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(xsltFile));
            Result res = new SAXResult(fop.getDefaultHandler());
            transformer.transform(xmlSource, res);
        } finally {
            out.close();
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:
As requested adding console log

> Mar 18, 2019 12:58:52 PM org.apache.fop.events.LoggingEventListener
>   processEvent WARNING: The following feature isn't implemented by
>   Apache FOP, yet: table-layout="auto" (on fo:table) (No context info
>   available) Mar 18, 2019 12:58:52 PM
>   org.apache.fop.events.LoggingEventListener processEvent WARNING: The
>   following feature isn't implemented by Apache FOP, yet:
>   table-layout="auto" (on fo:table) (No context info available) Mar 18,
>   2019 12:58:52 PM org.apache.fop.events.LoggingEventListener
>   processEvent SEVERE: Image not found. URI: ../Logo/IPTC_Logo.tif. (No
>   context info available) Mar 18, 2019 12:58:52 PM
>   org.apache.fop.events.LoggingEventListener processEvent SEVERE: Image
>   not found. URI: ../Logo/Separator.jpg. (No context info available) Mar
>   18, 2019 12:58:52 PM org.apache.fop.events.LoggingEventListener
>   processEvent SEVERE: Image not found. URI:
>   ../IPTC-19048-MS_fig_01.tif. (No context info available) Mar 18, 2019
>   12:58:52 PM org.apache.fop.events.LoggingEventListener processEvent
>   WARNING: The following feature isn't implemented by Apache FOP, yet:
>   table-layout="auto" (on fo:table) (No context info available) Mar 18,
>   2019 12:58:52 PM org.apache.fop.events.LoggingEventListener
>   processEvent WARNING: The following feature isn't implemented by
>   Apache FOP, yet: table-layout="auto" (on fo:table) (No context info
>   available) Mar 18, 2019 12:58:52 PM
>   org.apache.fop.events.LoggingEventListener processEvent SEVERE: Image
>   not found. URI: ../IPTC-19048-MS_fig_02.tif. (No context info
>   available) Mar 18, 2019 12:58:52 PM
>   org.apache.fop.events.LoggingEventListener processEvent WARNING: The
>   following feature isn't implemented by Apache FOP, yet:
>   table-layout="auto" (on fo:table) (No context info available) Mar 18,
>   2019 12:58:52 PM org.apache.fop.events.LoggingEventListener
>   processEvent SEVERE: Image not found. URI:
>   ../IPTC-19048-MS_fig_03.tif. (No context info available) Mar 18, 2019
>   12:58:52 PM org.apache.fop.events.LoggingEventListener processEvent
>   SEVERE: Image not found. URI: ../IPTC-19048-MS_fig_04.tif. (No context
>   info available) Mar 18, 2019 12:58:52 PM
>   org.apache.fop.events.LoggingEventListener processEvent SEVERE: Image
>   not found. URI: ../IPTC-19048-MS_fig_05.tif. (No context info
>   available) Mar 18, 2019 12:58:52 PM
>   org.apache.fop.events.LoggingEventListener processEvent SEVERE: Image
>   not found. URI: ../IPTC-19048-MS_fig_06.tif. (No context info
>   available) Mar 18, 2019 12:58:52 PM
>   org.apache.fop.events.LoggingEventListener processEvent SEVERE: Image
>   not found. URI: ../IPTC-19048-MS_fig_07.tif. (No context info
>   available) Mar 18, 2019 12:58:52 PM
>   org.apache.fop.events.LoggingEventListener processEvent WARNING: The
>   following feature isn't implemented by Apache FOP, yet:
>   table-layout="auto" (on fo:table) (No context info available) Mar 18,
>   2019 12:58:52 PM org.apache.fop.events.LoggingEventListener
>   processEvent WARNING: The following feature isn't implemented by
>   Apache FOP, yet: table-layout="auto" (on fo:table) (No context info
>   available) Mar 18, 2019 12:58:52 PM
>   org.apache.fop.events.LoggingEventListener processEvent SEVERE: Image
>   not found. URI: ../IPTC-19048-MS_fig_08.tif. (No context info
>   available) Mar 18, 2019 12:58:52 PM
>   org.apache.fop.events.LoggingEventListener processEvent SEVERE: Image
>   not found. URI: ../IPTC-19048-MS_fig_09.tif. (No context info
>   available) Mar 18, 2019 12:58:52 PM
>   org.apache.fop.events.LoggingEventListener processEvent SEVERE: Image
>   not found. URI: ../IPTC-19048-MS_fig_10.tif. (No context info
>   available) Mar 18, 2019 12:58:52 PM
>   org.apache.fop.events.LoggingEventListener processEvent WARNING: Font
>   "Arial,normal,700" not found. Substituting with "any,normal,700". Mar
>   18, 2019 12:58:52 PM org.apache.fop.events.LoggingEventListener
>   processEvent WARNING: Font "Symbol,normal,700" not found. Substituting
>   with "Symbol,normal,400". Mar 18, 2019 12:58:52 PM
>   org.apache.fop.events.LoggingEventListener processEvent INFO: An
>   fo:block  (No context info available) is wider than the available room
>   in inline-progression-dimension. Adjusting end-indent based on
>   overconstrained geometry rules (XSL 1.1, ch. 5.3.4) Mar 18, 2019
>   12:58:52 PM org.apache.fop.events.LoggingEventListener processEvent
>   WARNING: The contents of fo:block line 1 exceed the available area in
>   the inline-progression direction by 5880 millipoints. (No context info
>   available) Mar 18, 2019 12:58:52 PM
>   org.apache.fop.events.LoggingEventListener processEvent INFO: An
>   fo:block  (No context info available) is wider than the available room
>   in inline-progression-dimension. Adjusting end-indent based on
>   overconstrained geometry rules (XSL 1.1, ch. 5.3.4) Mar 18, 2019
>   12:58:52 PM org.apache.fop.events.LoggingEventListener processEvent
>   WARNING: The contents of fo:block line 1 exceed the available area in
>   the inline-progression direction by 5880 millipoints. (No context info
>   available) Mar 18, 2019 12:58:52 PM
>   org.apache.fop.events.LoggingEventListener processEvent INFO: An
>   fo:block  (No context info available) is wider than the available room
>   in inline-progression-dimension. Adjusting end-indent based on
>   overconstrained geometry rules (XSL 1.1, ch. 5.3.4) Mar 18, 2019
>   12:58:52 PM org.apache.fop.events.LoggingEventListener processEvent
>   WARNING: The contents of fo:block line 1 exceed the available area in
>   the inline-progression direction by 5880 millipoints. (No context info
>   available) Mar 18, 2019 12:58:52 PM
>   org.apache.fop.events.LoggingEventListener processEvent INFO: An
>   fo:block  (No context info available) is wider than the available room
>   in inline-progression-dimension. Adjusting end-indent based on
>   overconstrained geometry rules (XSL 1.1, ch. 5.3.4) Mar 18, 2019
>   12:58:52 PM org.apache.fop.events.LoggingEventListener processEvent
>   WARNING: The contents of fo:block line 1 exceed the available area in
>   the inline-progression direction by 5880 millipoints. (No context info
>   available) Mar 18, 2019 12:58:52 PM
>   org.apache.fop.events.LoggingEventListener processEvent INFO: An
>   fo:block  (No context info available) is wider than the available room
>   in inline-progression-dimension. Adjusting end-indent based on
>   overconstrained geometry rules (XSL 1.1, ch. 5.3.4) Mar 18, 2019
>   12:58:52 PM org.apache.fop.events.LoggingEventListener processEvent
>   WARNING: The contents of fo:block line 1 exceed the available area in
>   the inline-progression direction by 5880 millipoints. (No context info
>   available) Mar 18, 2019 12:58:53 PM
>   org.apache.fop.events.LoggingEventListener processEvent INFO: Rendered
>   page #1. Mar 18, 2019 12:58:53 PM
>   org.apache.fop.events.LoggingEventListener processEvent INFO: Rendered
>   page #2. Mar 18, 2019 12:58:53 PM
>   org.apache.fop.events.LoggingEventListener processEvent INFO: Rendered
>   page #3. Mar 18, 2019 12:58:53 PM
>   org.apache.fop.events.LoggingEventListener processEvent INFO: Rendered
>   page #4. Mar 18, 2019 12:58:53 PM
>   org.apache.fop.events.LoggingEventListener processEvent INFO: Rendered
>   page #5. Mar 18, 2019 12:58:53 PM
>   org.apache.fop.events.LoggingEventListener processEvent INFO: Rendered
>   page #6. Mar 18, 2019 12:58:53 PM
>   org.apache.fop.events.LoggingEventListener processEvent INFO: Rendered
>   page #7. Mar 18, 2019 12:58:53 PM
>   org.apache.fop.events.LoggingEventListener processEvent INFO: Rendered
>   page #8. Mar 18, 2019 12:58:53 PM
>   org.apache.fop.events.LoggingEventListener processEvent INFO: Rendered
>   page #9.

I have not written anything for formula in my xsl as I read JEuclid handles it.

Comment: Do you get any warning messages in the console log? Also, consider including a [short example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of FO file with a simple formula, for others to try and provide you precise help.

Comment: You can have a look at the resulting FO file calling FOP from the command line with the `-foout` option: `fop -xml IPTC-19048-MS.xml -xsl SPE.xsl -foout output.fo` (or using your xslt processor of choice to perform the transformation). This way you can check wheter there is actually some MathML in it or not, as the warning messages you are getting seem unrelated to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the mathml namespace on your fo:root tag? Like so:

```
<fo:root xmlns: fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:mathml="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
```

Comment: Yes, I do have namespace